# MongoDB retrieve only matching sub documents from a document with c#

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want the following query below to only return those sub documents from the **empActivity** array where the **Stamp** field in every sub document matches the **Stamp** value in the query. **empId** and **empActivity** are the outer level fields with **empActivity** having embedded documents.

```
db.emp_activity.find({$and : [{"empId" : "999"}, {"empActivity.Stamp" : { $lte : ISODate("2015-01-09T12:33:39.927Z")}}]})
```

The problem is that it also returns all the sub documents that dont match the date in the query, apart from the 4 sub documents having a date of 9th Jan 2015, the query above also returns sub documents whose date is greater than 9th Jan, 2015.

Comment: Look at the aggregation framework. Standard queries and projection will only match 1st elements. When you have more elements that match you need the aggregation framework. Many examples on StackOverflow.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks once again for the help, well i am aware of the aggregation framework , but i wanted to know if i could do the same via a query. How is the aggregation framework performance wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired output could be produce just by aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$match : { empId : '999', 'empActivity.Stamp' : { $lte : ISODate("2015-01-09T12:33:39.927Z")} }},
   {$unwind : '$empActivity'},
   {$match : { empId : '999', 'empActivity.Stamp' : { $lte : ISODate("2015-01-09T12:33:39.927Z")} }},
   {$group: { _id: '$empId', empActivity: { $addToSet: '$empActivity' }}}
])
```

in c#:

```
var args = new AggregateArgs
{
    Pipeline = new List<BsonDocument>
    {
        BsonDocument.Parse("{$match : { empId : '999', 'empActivity.Stamp' : { $lte : ISODate('2015-01-09T12:33:39.927Z')} }}"),
        BsonDocument.Parse("{$unwind : '$empActivity'}"),
        BsonDocument.Parse("{$match : { empId : '999', 'empActivity.Stamp' : { $lte : ISODate('2015-01-09T12:33:39.927Z')} }}"),
        BsonDocument.Parse("{$group: { _id: '$empId', empActivity: { $addToSet: '$empActivity' }}}"),
    }
};

var result = collection.Aggregate(args).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much appreciated, well as i said in my comments earlier, i am aware of aggregation but was just trying to figure out if i could do this with a query. Is the aggregation framework resource intensive?, how would you rate it performance wise?

Comment: aggregation is very fast, especially in cases it deals with small number of document (in your case using {$match : { empId : '999'}} causes to do the aggregate on small documents) http://vladmihalcea.com/2013/12/19/mongodb-facts-lightning-speed-aggregation/

Comment: @Neville Always worth mentioning to those new to the aggregation framework is **always $match first**. No point processing further operations like `$unwind` on documents that do not even contain a possible match in the array content. To filter arrays you can use `$match...$unwind..$match` for best performance. Or look at `$map` with `$setDifference` or `$redact` for other ways to filter array content.

Comment: @Disposer Thanks once again!