# The type or namespace AggregateArgs not found mognodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm doing an aggregation in C # to get get that only bring the sub set of an array, when instantiate AggregateArgs property, as not found

```js
   public async Task<List<Documents>> GetDocument(string ownerId, string dependentId)
        {

            var args = new AggregateArgs { 

            Pipeline = BsonDocument.Parse("$project: {Dependentsbenefits: {$filter: {input: $Dependentsbenefits, as: depend, cond:{ $eq: [$$depend.dependentId, " + dependentId + "] }}}}");
                  };

        var result = _employee.Aggregate(Pipeline).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the right version of the MongoDB Nuget package installed? Does your .NET Framework Target version on your project match the Mongo package? Usually this is the case.

Comment: I have MongoDB driver 2.8.0 installed Nuget package .

Comment: And what is the target .NET Framework version on your project? (right click Project properties -> build -> target version)

Comment: Is .NET Core 2.1

Comment: Did you add this Nuget package "MongoDB.Driver.Core" ?

Comment: Looks like AggregateArgs is possibly not supported under MongoDB.Driver.Core

Comment: Until now I had not, but. I've add  and did not solved

Comment: Doesn't look like this feature is supported in .NET Core library for MongoDB

Comment: I was trying to use this question for my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862389/mongodb-retrieve-only-matching-sub-documents-from-a-document-with-c-sharp

Comment: AggregateArgs is not supported in the .NET Core library of MongoDb from what I can see. You may need to use LINQ instead: https://www.qappdesign.com/mongodb-and-linq-how-to-aggregate-and-join-collections/